# applying the same operation to different dataframes

Tags: python, function, pandas, anonymous

couldnt find anything about this is python... 
ive been working on three different datasets for some machine learning projects and it has been a bit of an arduous task typing out the same commands in exactly the same way for the same operation on a different data frame... it started with this:

```
aviva =  pd.read_csv('data/LON_AV_.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date', date_parser=dateparse )
admiral= pd.read_csv('data/LON_ADM.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date', date_parser=dateparse )
three =  pd.read_csv('data/LON_III.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date', date_parser=dateparse )
```

in the middle there were many commands in applied to each dataframe that were the same

and ended with this:

```
three.to_csv('three_x.csv')
three_label.to_csv('three_y.csv')

admiral.to_csv('admiral_x.csv')
admiral_label.to_csv('admiral_y.csv')

aviva.to_csv('aviva_x.csv')
aviva_label.to_csv('aviva_y.csv')
```

my question to you guys is this, is there any way you have of speeding up the process so that I do not have to be repeating code like this all the time?
thank you guys and have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would do it this way:

```
in_csv_template = 'data/LON_{}.csv'
out_csv_template = 'out/{}_x.csv'
out_label_template = 'out/{}_y.csv'

cfg = {
    'aviva': 'AV_',
    'admiral': 'ADM',
    'three': 'III',
}

def process(fi_csv, fo_csv, fo_label, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_csv(fi_csv, **kwargs)

    ...

    df.to_csv(fo_csv)
    df_label.to_csv(fo_label)


for k,v in cfg.items():
    process(in_csv_template.format(v),
            out_csv_template.format(k),
            out_label_template.format(k),
            parse_dates=['Date'],
            index_col='Date',
            date_parser=dateparse)
```

Comment: good work man thank you thats pretty sweet, thts about as far automatic as I cwoudl be able to make it, nice one g

Answer (score 1):

Instead of three DataFrames, `aviva`, `admiral`, `three`, use one `dict` with keys of the same names which map to DataFrames:

```
dfs = dict()
for filename, name in [('LON_AV_.csv', 'aviva'), 
                       ('LON_ADM.csv', 'admiral'), 
                       ('LON_III.csv', 'three')]:
    dfs[name] = pd.read_csv('data/{}'.format(filename), parse_dates=['Date'], 
                            index_col='Date', date_parser=dateparse)

    ...

    dfs[name].to_csv('{}_x.csv'.format(name))
    label[name].to_csv('{}_y.csv'.format(name))
```